# I am getting This Error SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

There has been an error processing your request
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some issue with AWS hosting. Please restart your Apache and MySql, it will work fine.